# get a random Number no more then twice - Other Solution

Tags: actionscript-3, logic

Im trying to get a random number from the range of 0 to 2 (0,1,2),
but I only want to get the number 2 times in a row and after that it needs to be another number. Like this:

rand = 1(1st time), rand = 1(2nd time), rand = 1(3rd time -> we go and pick some other number(0 or 2))

currently I figured out a way, but I have a bad feeling that it isnt the best solution to this problem.

So I have this:

```
private var previousNumber:int = -1;
    private var sameNumber:int = 0;
    private var positions:Array = [0,1,2];

    private function randomNumber(maxNumber:int, minNumber:int = 0, calledFromInside:Boolean = false):int
    {
        var rand:int;
        var numberToReturn:int;

        if(!calledFromInside) 
        {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
            if( previousNumber == rand )
            {
                if( sameNumber < 2 )
                {
                    sameNumber++;
                    previousNumber = rand;
                    numberToReturn = positions[ rand ];
                }
                else
                {
                    positions.splice( rand, 1);
                    sameNumber = 0;
                    randomNumber(maxNumber, minNumber, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                previousNumber = rand;
                numberToReturn = positions[ rand ];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            maxNumber--;
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
            numberToReturn = positions[ rand ];
            positions = [0,1,2];
        }
        return numberToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you need exactly ? And what do you mean by "2 times in a row" ?

Comment: 2 times in a row means, that i dont want to get (lets say) number **Two**, no more then 2 consecutive times, and when it attempts to get again number **Two** (for the 3rd time), then I want it to return another number, which is different from **Two**. Basically Ive done it but .... I think its not the right way to do this - I overkilled it.

Comment: So you need 6 randomized generations for 0,1 and 2 twice for every value ?

Comment: :D nooo, basically what Im using this is to create and place elements at a certain position on the screen. Imagine they are spawned always at the top edge of the screen and falling dow, now 0 means - topLeft corner of the screen, 1- in the topMiddle of the screen, and 2 - topRight corner of the screen. So I never want to spawn 3 items (consecutive) in one position.
How many times they spawn doesnt matter, but lets say - infinite

Comment: But why you didn't tell us that from the beginning, it is easier to understand ;)

Comment: :D well I kinda tried to tell what I want (the shortest way) and not write anything that will confuse people. Guess it went the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-roll a random number each time you're encountering a third match.

```
private function randomNumber(maxNumber:int, minNumber:int = 0):int
{
    var rand:int= Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
    if (rand==previousNumber) 
    {
        sameNumber++; // matches previous
        while (sameNumber>2) // more than two in a row - uh oh
        { // start rolling until it'll be a different number
            rand= Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
            // reroll the number, just that, no recursion
            if (rand!=previousNumber) 
            { // we rolled a different number, clean up
                sameNumber=1;
                previousNumber=rand;
                return rand;
            }
        }
    } else {
        sameNumber=1;
        previousNumber=rand;
        return rand;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you can use a counter to count the generations number for every value and then you can accept it or request another value.

In my example, I used a button just to show the generated random value :

```
// save the generations count of every values
var count:Object = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0};

btn.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    function(e:MouseEvent):void { 
        trace(get_random_value());
    }
)

function get_random_value():int 
{
    var good:Boolean = false;
    var value:int;

    while(!good){

        // generate our random value, this instruction is good only for values between 0 and 2 for other values :
        // value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + max_value - min_value) + min_value);
        value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

        // if we have got this value once, so take it
        if(count[value] < 2)
        {
            good = true;

            // count ++
            count[value] ++;

            // if there is another value which has reached the max successive generations number (2) so initialize its count number
            init_others(value);

        // otherwise, we got this value twice, so try to get another value
        } else {            
            good = false;
        }
    }
    return value;
}

// initialize counter of values if equals 2
function init_others(me:int):void 
{
    for(var val in count){
        if(val != me && count[val] == 2) count[val] = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it is a bit hard for me to fallow, and I think the upper solution is simpler.

Comment: I don't know how it's hard this method ;) We count the number of every random value, if it's 2, then we have to get another one, that's all ! But the most important is that you have a solution for your problem.